# Disabling messages like "Windows Explorer has stopped working"

Tags: windows-7, teamviewer

I have a wierd question, not sure if it's possible...

We are a IT Company, we have over 50 computers using Teamviewer, these PC's are far away, and there is a problem when we use teamviewer...

When I connect to a computer via teamviewer, just a normal session. After ending the session, most of the time there comes up the error:

Windows Explorer has stopped working
Windows can try to restart the program.
 - **Restart the program**

This happens nearly everytime when closing a teamviewer session... I have found people with the same problem, but no solutions...

And the real problem is if I try to re-connect to the same computer I can't. If I manage to close the message on the PC locally I can start a session again with no problems, and if I close it again the errors can occur again, it's all random.

So my question to you is:
Can I remove this message to occur somehow? Like disabling some service.
Cause if I remove it, then explorer will still stop working but I don't have to press the **- Restart the program** button for it to work again... Cause it will do this automatically, right?

Or if there is some automated process that whenever the message occurs it automatically presses the **- Restart the program**

Comment: I'd contact TeamViewer support.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution would be to reinstall TeamViewer on every PC (do you have an deployment-Server, so that every PC automatically can reinstall it?)

And if explorer.exe stops working, it won't restart *itself*, which means, you'll have to do it yourself (with the Taskmanager)

I hope I could help you.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will fix the problem, We get new computers that we install teamviewer on everyday, the same thing happens with them right after a new installation on teamviewer...

Comment: ok alright then, did you try to contact the TeamViewer support? I'm pretty sure they will help you. So, this is the last thing I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. What I do is open task manager and end process for explorer.exe before I end the session.

But occasionally, Window Explorer stopped working when I'm in the middle of a session and there's nothing I can do about it.

It's not impossible to disable the message though but you'll have to mess around with the Regedit, which I don't highly recommend if you don't know what you're doing. It can ruin your PC once and for all if you mess it up.